# Removing the file:/// prefix from URL path

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I remove the file:/// prefix from the URL filepath:

```
 NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
```

Currently it prints as:

```
file:///Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EF752245-9692-4607-B84C-6133202A846B/data/Containers/Data/Application/08686F05-C513-4BDF-A20C-EF3AE1201D54/Documents/2017-02-12_1476366438.zip
```

EDIT:

I guess I could have done:

```
NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", [[filePath absoluteString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file:///" withString:@""]);
```

But isn't there anything build it to NSString that can remove that prefix?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`filePath.path` is what you're looking for. You don't want to "remove `file:///`." You just want the path part of the URL.

Note that this will leave the first `/`. I guess you could remove that, but it's unclear why that would be a good idea, since it's part of the path. (If you're gluing this together with other strings that might end in `/`, it's better to use path methods like `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` to get rid of doubled-slashes.)

Comment: Yeah, that makes total sense. Thanks a lot, Rob.

Comment: Worth noting for future readers—if you still want the full absolute path, change `file.path()` to `file.absoluteURL.path()`.

Answer (score -1):

For display purposes for URLs more generally, you can also do

```swift
String(url.absoluteString.dropFirst((url.scheme?.count ?? -3) + 3))
```